# Error with Selenium File Upload -> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, file-upload

Need to upload the `.mp3` file Using page object model
code:

```
@FindBy(xpath="//*[@class='iconmoon icon-upload-square f24 v-middle']/..")
    WebElement choosefile;
public void selectfile() throws InterruptedException {                                                                                                                                  
        log.info("element appearing ");
        Thread.sleep(5000);


        WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        WebElement element1 = wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(choosefile));
        //element1.click();
        //element1.sendKeys(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/extras/song2.mp3");   (way 1 passed path)
        element1.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\SS_Tops\\LabZ\\songs\\dfg.mp3"); (way 2)
        }
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="ButtonPanel uploadFileBox-btn">
  <div class="upload-file">
    <i class="iconmoon icon-upload-square f24 v-middle"></i>
    Browse files
    <input multiple="" type="file" id="browse-file">
  </div>
</div>
```

When I am trying to click the on this button the I can see the click & the window opened, but at the same time trying to pass the file it throws the error of:

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not
> interactable"

Comment: it's because you are sending keys to wrong element. you should pass it to element with xpath "//input[@type='file']" . And you don't need to click the button since sendKeys with filepath had done the job